# Improve tag wiki excerpts for [clang] and [clang++]

Tags: discussion, tag-excerpt

I'm not an expert at [clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clang) or [clang++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clang%2b%2b). I was attempting to retag a question, and stumbled on both of these with very similar tag excerpts. Can someone please improve them?

Comment: Just about none of these questions are actually about the clang++ driver for the clang compiler.  Questioners just use the tag that matches what they type at the command line :)  The tag wikis are correct.

Answer (score 12):

Clang is the name of the compiler. More precisely, it is a C, C++, Objective-C, and Objective-C++ front-end for the LLVM compiler.

`clang` is the command you type if you only want to link against the C standard library, while `clang++` links against both the C and C++ standard libraries. This default behavior can be overridden by explicitly specifying the libraries to link as arguments.

I'm not sure what the excerpts should say. You could give a short explanation like I did above of the names of the two front-end drivers, but the reality is there's no way to prevent [clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clang) from being used as a generic tag, considering it is also the name of the entire toolset. It's not as if we can use [clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clang) for C questions and [clang++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clang%2b%2b) for C++ questions.

I'm not a Clang expert either, so maybe someone can set me straight. But on first blush, I don't see why we need two separate tags. [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) and [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) should be more than enough to disambiguate.

Perhaps we should consider synonymizing the two?